# How to hide the scroll indicator on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Dear people of the Internet,
I have this css & html code to add an scroll indicator to my landing page.
My goal is; As soon as you scroll down, the indicator disappears and only appears again after reloading the page.
My jquery seems not to work, any help much appreciated!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

 if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
  {
     $('.scrolli').fadeOut();
  }
 });
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}
.scrolli{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.scrolli span{
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: -10px;
  animation: animate 2s infinite;
}
.scrolli span:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.scrolli span:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-20px,-20px);
  }
  50%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(20px,20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolli">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind select the question as accepted if you found it useful?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine, it doesn't work because there isn't any available scroll, so $(this).scrollTop() can't ever be greater than zero.

You can see it working by making the body taller:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

 if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
  {
     $('.scrolli').fadeOut();
  }
 });
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  height: 200vh;
}
.scrolli{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.scrolli span{
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: -10px;
  animation: animate 2s infinite;
}
.scrolli span:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.scrolli span:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-20px,-20px);
  }
  50%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(20px,20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrolli">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```